# Retrieving name from Firebase to table view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, tableview

Here's the dashboard for an iOS application:

```
{
"users" : {
"0b71693a-4f16-4759-acd6-706da1a466a0" : {
  "Picker" : "Jubail",
  "details" : "iOS second",
  "name" : "Huda"
},
"16b13b1e-0025-4eee-a590-5bbacc52071c" : {
  "Picker" : "Jeddah",
  "details" : "Hellom from the Internet",
  "name" : "Rania"
   },
 "394b6555-1838-4565-87ac-e423c3b89cf1" : {
  "Picker" : "Jubail",
  "details" : "",
  "name" : "Marwa"
},
         }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the names for all users whose picker is Jubail to table view cells!

I'm so a beginner at swift, I did not know how to do it!
I tried, here's the code I did:

```
 import UIKit
class CookingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var BusinessName:[String: String] = [String:String]()

let ref = Firebase (url: "https://mariahfinaltest.firebaseio.com")

@IBOutlet weak var CookingTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref.queryOrderedByChild("Picker").queryEqualToValue("Riyadh")
        .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
               self.BusinessName = child.value["name"] as! [String: String]
            }
            self.CookingTableView.reloadData()
        })
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5 //It should not be 5 here! How Can I make it as long as cells?
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.CookingTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CookingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CookingTableViewCell

    var keys: Array = Array(self.BusinessName.keys)
    cell.BusinessNameLabel.text = BusinessName[keys[indexPath.row]] as String!
    return cell

}
}
```

I keep getting errors! 
I don't know what's wrong!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty close

It's most likely crashing due to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5 //It should not be 5 here! How Can I make it as long as cells?
}
```

This is telling your tableView it has 5 items, which if it doesn't will cause out of range values and crash.

so here's simplified design pattern.

```
var namesArray: [String]

ref.queryOrderedByChild("Picker").queryEqualToValue("Riyadh")
    .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
           let name = child.value["name"] as! String
           self.namesArray.append(name)
        }
        self.CookingTableView.reloadData()
})
```

then your tableView delegate methods

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return namesArray.count //return the number of items in the array
    }
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
     let name = namesArray[indexPath.row]
     cell.textLabel?.text = name
     return cell
    }
```

Comment: I understand my last mistake and It worked, also there was a  problem with the firebase url! I did not add "/users" in the url.

Comment: @Jay please answer this like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646255/retrieve-all-child-value-to-a-label-in-table-view-cell

Comment: @Xcodian Do you have a question? If so, please post it so we can take a look at your use case!

Comment: @Jay yes, sir, i have posted here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646255/retrieve-all-child-value-to-a-label-in-table-view-cell